# ANTLR-like API for clang AST

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, antlr4

Total clang/llvm n00b here. I'm building a multilingual static analysis tool which has parsers for individual languages export an appropriately tagged language-agnostic AST for a single analyser binary to process. So far I've been using native parsers for Ruby and Go and ANTLR-based one for Swift.

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) in particular won my heart because of it's [Listener API](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeListener.html) where 3 generic methods are provided:

```
void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) 
void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) 
void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node)
```

You can also subscribe to `enter` and `exit` events for particular rules that you find particularly interesting. So for a given rule you'd have four callbacks triggered - `enterEveryRule`, `enterParticularRule`, `exitParticularRule`, `exitEveryRule` - in this particular order. There is also concept of `TerminalNode`s which are things like literals etc.

Since this sort an API what feels most natural for the task at hand I would kindly like to solicit your advice on how to go about replicating it in clang. I went through [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805595/how-to-traverse-clang-ast-manually) and I got some inspiration but I still don't know how to go about terminal nodes.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How is this different than "walk the tree" and test for the nodes you care about?  As a matter of practicality, you really want a lot more capability for pattern matching against complex trees (try writing the code recognize a complex statement) and extracting facts from near and far points in the code.  This API gives almost nothing for that.

Comment: @IraBaxter I'm using a stack to generate the language-agnostic AST (a  Protocol Buffers message) so I like how I can take something off the stack in an `onExit` callback. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are two questions, really - 1) how to provide `onExit` callbacks; 2) what would be the clang's equivalent of ANTLR's terminal nodes;

Comment: If you do a treewalk, you can still manage your own stack and push and pop as you like, so I still don't see the point.  (I don't believe in the "language agnostic AST";; too hard to model the precise semantics, e.g.,  What will you do with "add" to capture the differences, so good luck with that).

Comment: @IraBaxter It's no longer an AST, really but something that the analyser consumes to calculate a number of metrics. So no need to model the precise semantics. What I don't understand is how the AST walk tells me that we've already processed an entire subtree (which is what would trigger the `onExit` callback). For example this is accomplished in Go API by a call with nil argument: https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Visitor