# VisitDecl vs. TraverseDecl (Clang RecursiveASTVisitor)

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, llvm-clang

I've read this link but still don't fully understand what's the difference between TraverseDecl and VisitDecl (and their use case) http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html

Which method should I be overriding when writing my RecursiveASTVisitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TraverseDecl tells the frontend library's ASTConsumer to visit declarations recursively from the AST. Then VisitDecl is called where you can extract the relevant information.

Follow these two links for more details and a simple checker example:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html

[How to traverse clang AST manually ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805595/how-to-traverse-clang-ast-manually)

Comment: Are there any difference to using TraverseDecl or VisitDecl within the ASTVisitor though. In the example, TraverseDecl is used within ASTConsumer and VisitDecl in the ASTVisitor. However, the other stackoverflow link has TraverseDecl within ASTVisitor itself.

Comment: [RecursiveASTVisiter](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html) 
If you look at the detailed description in the link: You can see that traverseDecl will come at an upper tier than visitDecl. So if it were up to me I will follow [Clang Plugin](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) example as it maintains that hierarchy and is more understandable.

Comment: That means to use Traverse within the ASTConsumer and Visits within ASTVisitor? Mhmm.

Comment: To be a little honest with you, I am also relatively new to Clang. But, from what I understand it is, in fact, more intuitive to do visits in ASTVisitor and not in ASTConsumer. If you look at the VISITOR Pattern that might help to get the intuition behind why ASTVisitors are implemented the way they are implemented.