# How can I get a clang::QualType from a string?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-static-analyzer

I'm working on a custom checker for the clang static analyzer that checks for incorrect use of CPython APIs.  I've made some progress, but I'm stuck: how can I get a `clang::QualType` value given the name of a type?

For example, I'd like to write something like this:

```
QualType ty = findTheTypeNamed("Py_ssize_t");
```

I've spent time looking at the code for `clang::ASTContext` and `clang::QualType`, but I'm lost.

How can I get a `clang::QualType` from the name of a type?

Comment: I don't have a great answer, but if you have the CompilerInstance, you can create a matcher that will let you specify the name.   Or you can set up your own recursive visitor: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html.  To set up a matcher, you can look at some awful code I wrote here: https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit/blob/master/tools/class_parser.cpp#L2935

Comment: Here's a question/answer with more details on doing the recursive traversal yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805595/how-to-traverse-clang-ast-manually   Unfortunately, I think there may not be a "quick" answer.   Maybe do a full traversal (or very generic matcher) and do a one-time cache of all the names => qualtype mappings ?

Answer (score 2):

The `asString` [narrowing matcher](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html#narrowing-matchers) turns a string into a qualtype.

Here is the associated documentation :

```
Matches if the matched type is represented by the given string.

Given
  class Y { public: void x(); };
  void z() { Y* y; y->x(); }
cxxMemberCallExpr(on(hasType(asString("class Y *"))))
  matches y->x()
```